# How to Fix Accidental Deletion of librpm.so.3

Tags: yum, rpm, libraries

I was dealing with a series of duplicates in my Fedora 20 installation, and was deleting them 10 at a time. It seems however that I've deleted `librpm.so.3` and now I get the following message with running `sudo yum update`:

> There was a problem importing one of the Python modules
>   required to run yum. The error leading to this problem was:
>
> librpm.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
>
> Please install a package which provides this module, or    verify
>   that the module is installed correctly.
>
> It's possible that the above module doesn't match the    current
>   version of Python, which is:
>      2.7.5 (default, Sep 25 2014, 13:57:38)     [GCC 4.8.3 20140911 (Red Hat 4.8.3-7)]
>
> If you cannot solve this problem yourself, please go to     the yum
>   faq at:    http://yum.baseurl.org/wiki/Faq

Can anyone please tell me how to can fix this, and give me the steps. I'm only halfway decent with Fedora, but can follow instructions.... here's my Fedora version if helpful:

```
Linux localhost.localdomain 3.11.10-301.fc20.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Dec 5 14:01:17 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Thnaks.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your `rpm` command won't work now, so even if you download the relevant package (`rpm-libs`) you won't be able to restore the files on your current installation.

Some options are:

- You could try copying the file from another Fedora 20 machine.
- You could fire up the install/live CD or USB-stick and copy the file from there (if it's the correct version)
- Again, with the install/live CD or USB-stick (or another RPM based system) you could download the correct version of `rpm-libs` and extract the files (this package isn't relocatable so you can't use the `--prefix` option to force `rpm` to install it in a different location). You'll therefore need to `rpm2cpio rpm-libs-<version etc>.rpm | cpio -idmv` within a temporary directory.  Then, copy the relevant file to your system.

Comment: I have finally found my files, but when I attempt to drag them into lib64, they won't go. I see in the directory, the old one have an "X" as opposed to the "arrow".I cannot remember my `su` password, so I just use `sudo su`... can you provide me with the proper script to insert the files into the lib64 directory? Thanks.

Comment: At the shell, type `sudo -i` and enter you user password.  You'll now be `root`. Use `cp <source> <destination> to copy it to the new destination.  If you have `SELinux` enabled, then follow it with `restorecon <destination>`.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the build tools needed for your system?  If so:

1. Download the appropriate version from the [RPM Website](http://www.rpm.org/wiki/Download)
2. `tar -xvjpf rpm-version.tar.bz2`
3. `cd rpm-version`
4. `./configure`
5. `make`
6. `make install`

**Please note**: `version` is the version number you decide to download.

After installing the compiled version of rpm, use `rpm -i rpm` to reinstall your Distribution's version of rpm then use yum.  As gareth states, you have created a circular dependancy, and if you haven't installed the `build-tools` and `fakeroot` packages, you'll even be SOL with my approach.